# Finding interior angles of a triangle using PyQGIS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, angles

I need interior angles of a triangle (`QgsTriangle` object). It has `angles()` method. There is an example in [documentation](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsTriangle.html#a1fabeedee3155a1b17ccbd2e34a64828). But sometimes the method doesn't give correct results I expect.

For example:

```
from math import degrees

triangle = QgsTriangle( QgsPointXY(0, 0), QgsPointXY(1, 2), QgsPointXY(2, 0) )
angles = [ round(degrees(a), 2) for a in triangle.angles() ]
print(angles)

# Out: [26.57, 36.87, 26.57]
```

[image]

If I change the order of the first two points I get the correct result. But it depends.

```
triangle = QgsTriangle( QgsPointXY(1, 2), QgsPointXY(0, 0), QgsPointXY(2, 0) )
angles = [ round(degrees(a), 2) for a in triangle.angles() ]
print(angles)

# Out: [53.13, 63.43, 63.43]
```

I checked the source code of `angles()` method. It uses `QgsGeometryUtils.angleBetweenThreePoints` method.

I don't determine the order of the points. It comes from `QgsGeometry`object. So how can I be sure that the `angles()` method always gives the correct angle values?

Comment: It would have been better if you had reported one years ago this bug in the QGIS repository https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues, so the bug would have been fixed since then.
Anyway the bug was reported today and the issue is being fixed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The sum of inner angles in a triangle is always 180 degrees. So, by using itertools permutations method, you can select only first combination where this condition is fullfilled. Following code prints all possibilities.

```
from math import degrees
import itertools

points = [QgsPointXY(0, 0), QgsPointXY(1, 2), QgsPointXY(2, 0)]
n = len(points)
per = range(n)

for i, j, k in itertools.permutations(per, 3):
    print (i, j, k)

    triangle = QgsTriangle( points[i], points[j], points[k])
    angles = [ round(degrees(a), 2) for a in triangle.angles() ]
    print(sum(angles))

0 1 2
90.00999999999999
0 2 1
179.99
1 0 2
179.99
1 2 0
90.00999999999999
2 0 1
90.00999999999999
2 1 0
179.99
```

Adapting above code for printing point indices and angles if that condition is fulfilled (first of them because there are three possibilities), it results in:

```
from math import degrees
import itertools

points = [QgsPointXY(0, 0), QgsPointXY(1, 2), QgsPointXY(2, 0)]
n = len(points)
per = range(n)

for i, j, k in itertools.permutations(per, 3):
    triangle = QgsTriangle( points[i], points[j], points[k])
    angles = [ round(degrees(a), 2) for a in triangle.angles() ]
    sum_angles = sum(angles)
    diff = 180 - sum_angles
    if diff < 1e-2:
        print(i, j, k)
        print(angles[i], angles[j], angles[k])
        print (diff)
        break

0 2 1
63.43 53.13 63.43
0.009999999999990905
```